# The second of two marginnotes in a Hebrew document is superimposed on the main text

Tags: luatex, margins, babel, hebrew

**A demonstration of the problem via a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
מכל אלה שהתהלכתי אתם פעם בעיר מולדתי יקרה לי ביחוד%
\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{%
שלום רב שובך, ציפורה נחמדת, מארצות החום אל חלוני.%
}} %LTR
בת שכננו מינה, אשר קראו לה גם בשם הגנאי ה’ברודה',%
\marginnote{\textcolor{red}{%
אל קולך כי ערב מה-נפשי כלתה בחורף בעוזבך מעוני.
}}% LTR
והיא נערה מנומרת בכתמי שמש שלא חוננה אמנם ביופי, אבל הן כבר ידוע המשפט של כלי החרס אשר בהם ישומר היין הטוב, וראינו גם אשר דברי אלהים חיים נכתבים על גויל פשוט.
\end{document}
```

The code creates a document of class `article`, sets its main (and only) language to Hebrew, and, in the document's body, writes a paragraph of Hebrew text, in which two `marginnote`s of Hebrew text are embedded in two locations. The text of the first `marginnote` is colored blue, whereas that of the second one is colored red.

Before compiling the code, I took preemptive steps to avoid [a known issue concerning `marginnote`s in Hebrew documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638854/21685), by implementing a variation on [David Carlisle's hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638855/21685): I made a local copy of `marginnote.sty` (originally in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/`), and replaced its line no. 363 with: `\rlap{\kern-2.7\marginparwidth%`.<sup>see footnote</sup>

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> lualatex Test
```

The compilation completed successfully with no warnings in `~/Test.log`; in particular, no warnings suggesting to rerun the compilation.

As a result of the compilation, the file `~/Test.pdf` was created. When this file was opened in a PDF viewer, it displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: Two Hebrew margin notes in a Hebrew document]

As can be seen, the first (blue) `marginnote` is positioned correctly in the margin, but the second (red) `marginnote` is superimposed on the main text.

---

**Questions**

1. Why is the second margin note superimposed on the main text?
2. What can I do to fix the position of the second (and any other) margin note, while preserving the now correct position of the first margin note?

---

**Footnote**

It was Udi Fogiel, in a comment to a previous post of mine now deleted (due to being a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638854/21685)), who made me aware of the hack, and suggested the variation necessary to adapt it to the `babel`+`lualatex` combo that I use.

Comment: It might be a problem with LuaTeX and bidi, with XeTeX and polyglossia i don't get that problem.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Good to know,  but switching to XeTeX+Polyglossia is not an option for me.

Comment: rename the sty if you change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This here seems to be the correct values. Attention! It doesn't handle reversemarginpar, and twoside hasn't been tested yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern-\dimexpr\@mn@currxpos}{\kern\dimexpr\@mn@currxpos}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern\oddsidemargin}{\kern-\oddsidemargin}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern\oddsidemargin}{\kern-\oddsidemargin}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern\evensidemargin}{\kern-\evensidemargin}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern 1in}{\kern-1in}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@mn@@@marginnote{\kern\marginnotetextwidth}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
מכל אלה שהתהלכתי אתם פעם בעיר מולדתי יקרה לי ביחוד%
\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{%
שלום רב שובך, ציפורה נחמדת, מארצות החום אל חלוני.%
}} %LTR
בת שכננו מינה, אשר קראו לה גם בשם הגנאי ה’ברודה',%
\marginnote{\textcolor{red}{%
אל קולך כי ערב מה-נפשי כלתה בחורף בעוזבך מעוני.
}}% LTR
והיא נערה מנומרת בכתמי שמש שלא חוננה אמנם ביופי, אבל הן כבר ידוע המשפט של כלי החרס אשר בהם 
ישומר היין הטוב, וראינו גם אשר דברי אלהים חיים נכתבים על גויל פשוט. 
',%
\marginnote{\textcolor{green}{%
אל קולך כי ערב מה-נפשי כלתה בחורף בעוזבך מעוני.
}}% LTR
והיא נערה מנומרת בכתמי שמש שלא חוננה אמנם ביופי, אבל הן כבר ידוע המשפט של כלי החרס אשר בהם 
ישומר היין הטוב, וראינו גם אשר דברי אלהים חיים נכתבים על גויל פשוט. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to load tikz and zref-savepos?

Comment: @UdiFogiel no, that are remains from the tests, I will edit.

Comment: Thank you! Does your solution need to be used in conjunction with Udi Fogiel's suggestion to my previous post of making a local copy of `marginnote.sty` and changing its line no. 363? Or does your answer provide a complete solution to the two issues described both in the present question as well as in the previous one?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: It appears to be a complete solution to the two issues, rendering it unnecessary to make a local copy of `marginnote.sty`.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, `marginnote` takes into account RTL texts, but this feature is activated only when `bidi` is loaded. Apparently, it can be cheated in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL  \@RTLtrue  % Pretend that `bidi` has been loaded 
\makeatother

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
מכל אלה שהתהלכתי אתם פעם בעיר מולדתי יקרה לי ביחוד%
\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{%
שלום רב שובך, ציפורה נחמדת, מארצות החום אל חלוני.%
}} %LTR
בת שכננו מינה, אשר קראו לה גם בשם הגנאי ה’ברודה',%
\marginnote{\textcolor{red}{%
אל קולך כי ערב מה-נפשי כלתה בחורף בעוזבך מעוני.
}}% LTR
והיא נערה מנומרת בכתמי שמש שלא חוננה אמנם ביופי, אבל הן כבר ידוע המשפט של כלי החרס אשר בהם ישומר היין הטוב, וראינו גם אשר דברי אלהים חיים נכתבים על גויל פשוט.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I compile your code twice with `lualatex` the resulting PDF looks [like this](https://imgur.com/a/swmBurG). In particular, the margin notes are rendered inside the text area and overlap the main text.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe the versions are not the same.

Comment: Sorry. I had a modified local copy of marginnote.sty in my testing folder, left over from a hack suggested to a previous post of mine (now deleted). I now removed the local copy, and the PDF file produced by your code looks as expected.

Comment: Is it safe to add your code to documents that don't use bidi? How about if they don't even use `babel`?

Comment: It's difficult to know what can happen when one is cheating, but in most cases these definitions should be harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following piece of code after loading the `marginnote` package to (hopefully) correct `marginnote`'s `\@mn@if@RTL` which is supposed to test whether the current text flow is RTL or not.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@mn@if@RTL}%
{%
   \ifthenelse%
   {\equal{\the\textdir}{\detokenize{TRT}}}%
   {\@firstoftwo}%
   {\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother
```

The `geometry` package should also be loaded if there are margin notes in LTR text, I don't know why, but otherwise the horizontal alignment of the marginnotes is a little off.

This solution relies on the LuaTeX engine's register `\textdir`, so can be used only with LuaTeX.

---

An example with both text and math in document whose language is set to Hebrew via `babel`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% marginnote fix begin
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@mn@if@RTL}%
{%
   \ifthenelse%
   {\equal{\the\textdir}{\detokenize{TRT}}}%
   {\@firstoftwo}%
   {\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother
% marginnote fix end
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1][1-1] \marginnote{Margin note in text mode}
\lipsum[1-1][2-8]
\reversemarginpar
\[
x + y = z\marginnote{Margin note in math mode}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Margin notes from text and math in a Hebrew document]

---

The example of the original post:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% marginnote fix begin
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@mn@if@RTL}%
{%
   \ifthenelse%
   {\equal{\the\textdir}{\detokenize{TRT}}}%
   {\@firstoftwo}%
   {\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother
% marginnote fix end
\begin{document}
מכל אלה שהתהלכתי אתם פעם בעיר מולדתי יקרה לי ביחוד%
\marginnote{\textcolor{blue}{%
שלום רב שובך, ציפורה נחמדת, מארצות החום אל חלוני.%
}} %LTR
בת שכננו מינה, אשר קראו לה גם בשם הגנאי ה’ברודה',%
\marginnote{\textcolor{red}{%
אל קולך כי ערב מה-נפשי כלתה בחורף בעוזבך מעוני.
}}% LTR
והיא נערה מנומרת בכתמי שמש שלא חוננה אמנם ביופי, אבל הן כבר ידוע המשפט של כלי החרס אשר בהם ישומר היין הטוב, וראינו גם אשר דברי אלהים חיים נכתבים על גויל פשוט.
\end{document}
```

[image: Two overlapping margin notes]

In this case the loading of the `geometry` package is optional, because the text is entirely RTL.

---

**Acknowledgments**

1. Ulrike Fischer for [telling me about the `\textdir` register](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670186/how-to-find-out-if-the-direction-of-text-flow-is-right-to-left-or-left-to-right#comment1665810_670186).
2. David Carlisle for [showing me how to query said register](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670198/21685).

---

**Remarks**

This is not a perfect solution. There are cases in which despite the implementation of this solution, the margin notes are misplaced, for instance the following example in which the document's left and right margins are asymetrical.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:3,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, english, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@mn@if@RTL}%
{%
   \ifthenelse%
   {\equal{\the\textdir}{\detokenize{TRT}}}%
   {\@firstoftwo}%
   {\@secondoftwo}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\reversemarginpar
\[%LTR
x + y = z\marginnote{math note}
\]
\normalmarginpar
word\marginpar{text note}
\end{document}
```

[image: Asymetrical margins]

Comment: +1 Great solution! is there anyway doing that using conditionals from the latex kernel only and not loading `ifthen`?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the output of the original `\@mn@if@RTL` is `\expandafter\@firstoftwo`, or `\expandafter\@secondoftwo`. There might be an important expansion order in some cases. Is there a reason i missed for why you dropped the `\expandafter` prefix? I'm not sure about what should be the correct implementation.

Comment: @UdiFogiel 1. "Great solution" - Thanks. 2. "Is there anyway doing that [...] not loading `ifthen`?" - I'm sure there's a way of doing that without loading `ifthen`, but I don't know how off the top of my head, and I don't feel like spending time exploring this at the moment.

Comment: @UdiFogiel 3. "I've noticed that the output of the original `\@mn@if@RTL` is \expandafter\@firstoftwo [...] Is there a reason i missed for why you dropped the `\expandafter`?" Yes, there's a reason you missed. The only way `\@mn@if@RTL` is used in the `marginnote` code is as follows: `\@mn@if@RTL{\PackageInfo{marginnote}...` When `\@mn@if@RTL` expands to, say, `\expandafter\@firstoftwo`, the `\expandafter` will expand the left brace `{` just following the token `\@mn@if@RTL`, which doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation