# A marginnote in an equation is not typeset in a Hebrew document

Tags: luatex, babel, geometry, hebrew, marginnote

**A description of the problem by way of a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:4]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL  \@RTLtrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
x + y = z\marginnote{Hello, world!}
\]
\end{document}
```

The code creates a document of class `article`, and adjusts the relative width of the article's left and right margins. It then establishes Hebrew as the document's main, and only language via the `babel` package. Then, after loading the `marginnote` package, it implements [a hack suggested by Javier Bezos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670052/21685) to resolve an issue arising when the `marginnote` package interacts with Hebrew documents managed by `babel`. Then, in the document's body, an equation, in which a margin note is embedded, is written in display mode.

Then I executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> lualatex Test
```

The compilation completed successfully, with no warning in `~/Test.log`; in particular, no warning suggesting to rerun `lualatex`. As a consequence of the compilation, the file `~/Test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer the file displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: No margin note]

As can be seen, there's no margin note on the page.

**Questions**

1. Why wasn't the margin note printed out?
2. What can I do to make the margin note appear without giving up on the elements that make up the preamble: the `geometry` package with adjusted margins, the `babel` package with Hebrew as the main language, and Javier Bezos' hack. (Actually, the hack can be done away with, as long as it is replaced by another solution to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669970/21685), but I'd prefer it if Bezos' elegant hack could be retained.)

Comment: I wouldn't use the `\@RTLtrue` hack. That is clearly meant for compatibility with the bidi package and so for xelatex but the bidi models of xelatex and lualatex are different.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The same problem occurs if Bezos' hack is replaced by [your patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669985/21685) (at least in Overleaf, my normal computer is not currently at my disposal).

Comment: well math is left to right isn't it? So you probably need the unpatch version.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I have the patched and the unpatched versions in the same document? If I insert `\let\mymarginnote\marginnote` after `\usepackage{marginnote}` but before your patch, and use `\mymarginnote` inside the equation instead of `\marginnote`, I get the same erroneous result.

Comment: You can try if it works if you use Javier's method and switch to `\@RTLfalse` before the equation. But imho you will have to properly test and adapt  marginnote. That mean make a copy, e.g. bidi-marginnote, and then study the code and test changes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Your last suggestion worked insofar as the margin note became visible. However, it is placed in the right margin, whereas it should be placed in the left margin, since the document's main language is Hebrew, and all margin notes should by default be placed in the same margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Qustion 1

The margin note actually is printed out, but, because the margin note is typeset inside math mode, the direction of kerning (which the package `marginnote` heavily rely upon) is opposite to that outside of math mode, which makes the margin note flush outside the right margin of the page (due to wrong calculation of the package, that expected kerning to be done to the right).

You can observe that by moving your margin note more to the left

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:4]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL  \@RTLtrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \[
    x + y = z\marginnote{Hello, world!}\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Question 2

You can exit math mode by entering restricted horizontal mode (via `\hbox`) and restore the direction of `\pardir` and `\textdir` (that has changed inside math mode)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:4,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL  \@RTLtrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \[
    x + y = z\hbox{\pardir TRT \textdir TRT\marginnote{Hello, world!}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

but it might be better to use `\hboxR` from `luabidi`, which does essentially the same, but is more robust

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:4,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{luabidi}
\makeatletter
\@RTLtrue % luabidi already defines this conditional
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \[
    x + y = z\hboxR{\marginnote{Hello, world!}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the LuaTex `\hboxR` solution with `\marginnote`'s `voffset` optional argument, which moves the margin note vertically relative to the position it would be placed at if the optional argument weren't given?

Comment: @EvanAad Do you mean something like `x + y = z\hboxR{\marginnote{Hello, world!}[200pt]}`? seems to be working.