# Margin notes don't show up in a Hebrew document

Tags: babel, marginnote, right-to-left

I am working on a Hebrew document, and I want to add margin notes. When I do this in an English document, everything works fine:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\geometry{left=0.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, marginparwidth=2cm}
% \reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Hello}
\marginnote{Hi}
\end{document}
```

and I get:

[image]

When I load `babel` and add the necessary code to get a Hebrew document, the margin note disappears:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\geometry{left=0.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, marginparwidth=2cm}
% \reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{שלום}
\marginnote{היי}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I tried to use `\reversemarginpar` and it didn't work. I also gave the option `showframe` to the `geometry` package to make sure there is enough space for the note, and it looks fine. I can't understand why I can't get the margin note to show correctly in my Hebrew document.

Comment: Does the note show up if you run a second pass?

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnCsJ.png the layout you are looking for? Then maybe try with `\makeatletter
\newif\if@RTL  \@RTLtrue
\makeatother`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678054/36296

Comment: Why `\marginnote` and not `\marginpar`?

Comment: @cabohah (as I guess you may know) `marginnote` allows you to put a note inside things; `marginpar` only works if you are in regular "outer" paragraph mode.

Comment: @Thruston I know this, but in the example I cannot see any reasin to use `\marginnote` instead of `\marginpar`. And I often see that beginners use `\marginnote` when `\marginpar` would be sufficient.

Comment: @cabohah fair point...